# How to specify Iterator types in generic?

Tags: rust, iterator, ref, borrowing

This question is based on [this code from the url crate](https://github.com/servo/rust-url/blob/7d2c9d6ceb3307a3fad4c4bcb7f5b07b5e24c755/src/form_urlencoded.rs#L276).

The `extend` method receives an iterator over tuples with objects which may be borrowed as `&str`.

```rust
fn extend<I, K, V>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Borrow<(K, V)>,
    K: AsRef<str>,
    V: AsRef<str>
{
    {
        for key in iter {
            let (ref k, ref v) = key.borrow();
            append(k.as_ref(), v.as_ref());
        }
    }
}
```

[Full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=213314dedd6c4f251d162b92fe8c573e).

I want the `extend` method to deal with an iterator over `(&str, Option<&str>)` tuples. I tried different variants like:

```rust
fn extend<I, K, V>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Borrow<(K, Option<V>)>,
    K: AsRef<str>,
    V: AsRef<str>
```

but I don't understand how it works.

How can I explain what I want to the compiler?

Comment: Then I guess the bound should be `I: IntoIterator<Item = (&K, Option<&V>)>`

Comment: [This 2 and 3](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f4d2e8128bedb040f23d416667f6e62d) variants don't work.
What I did wrong?

Comment: the `K: AsRef<str>, V: AsRef<str>` bounds are missing in `extend3`.

Comment: Turned out that it works [this way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0ad16a79facd03590abddd17fcb3f8c). Closer to @ttarikbnr solution.

Comment: And [also this way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b573b821e4113cbd8ebd2ecb84fa8b9d). The problem is I don't understand why [append works but append2 don't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e050b617bd3216489b4b269b216e101).

Comment: You need to convert the `Option<V>` to a `Option<&str>`, which you can do with `v.as_ref().map(|v| v.as_ref())`

Comment: Also, you don't need `ref`, Rust has match ergonomics. Just write `let (k, v) = pair.borrow();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need references in the tuple:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e8c7000214513aec00b7de7d7d9b4e6f)

```
fn extend<I, K, V>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Borrow<(K, V)>,
    K: AsRef<str>,
    V: AsRef<str>,
{
    for key in iter {
        let (k, v) = key.borrow();
        append(k.as_ref(), v.as_ref());
    }
}

fn extend2<I, K, V>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = (K, Option<V>)>,
    K: AsRef<str>,
    V: AsRef<str>,
{
    for (k, v) in iter {
        append3(k, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "You don't need references in the tuple." The example in the playgroup doesn't work if I remove `Borrow` from `fn extend`:
      `error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving <std::slice::Iter<'_, (&str, &str)> as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == (_, _)

Comment: @Aloso, looks like it works. But what the difference? Wont it be one more copying?

Comment: OK. Last [variation is this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a373db5cd1a69b186b36f0ec5c1447a). It doesn't required **.iter().copied()** and lifetime at **apply**.